# Modify internalip of node in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

I think I just need to modify the internal ip of a worker node to get it back because its static Ip had changed.

I tried without success:

```
kubectl patch node mynode -p '{"status": {"addresses": [{ "address": "44.33.22.11", "type": "InternalIP" }] } }'
```

> node "mynode" not patched

What is the way to modify the worker internalip from master node and get it back ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the below way to update worker node IP address:

1. Execute `kubeadm reset` on worker node.
2. Change IP address using `ifconfig <network interface> <IP address>` command.
3. Add node again using `kubeadm join` command.

Note, if you added custom IP addresses for worker Nodes to `/etc/hosts`, don’t forget to change it there.

Comment: It seems the only way is to rejoin the master as you answer.